# How can I style CellList items on a per-item basis?

Tags: gwt, celllist

I have a CellList in GWT 2.5. Each cell item is a class based on AbstractCell and defined in a UiBinder file.

How can I set different styles for each item? I'd like some to appear in a "disabled" style and others in an "active" style.

This is the content from my .ui.xml file. I've not included the style definitions or UiBinder scaffolding.

```
<div class="{style.contact}">
    <div>
        <div>
            <img class="{style.photo}" src="{photo}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="{style.names}">
            <div>
                <p><ui:text from="{name}"/></p>
                <p><ui:text from="{jobTitle}"/></p>
                <p><ui:text from="{company}"/></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CellList.getRowElement()`:

```
cellList.getRowElement(3).addClassName("css-disabled");
cellList.getRowElement(4).addClassName("css-active");
```

Comment: After trying the suggested approach and finding it didn't work it looks like GWT CellList has it very own special API for handling style changes.

Comment: @Carl try put important! In the style.

Comment: I tried !important but there was no effect. the "addClassName()" is disconnected from the html being rendered. When I look using Developer toolbar I can't even find any element with the class name "css-disabled".

Comment: ah... as I'm using ListDataProvider one is whistling in the wind if want interacts with an Element straight after adding a component to the CellList. So... call addClassName() "later" and the call will work. I'm still left to work out how to make the addClassName() sooner but that's a different question! :)

Comment: no because if you don't add the component first, the element does not even exist. You can't add class or modify anything to an element that does not exist.

Comment: texasbruce... the call addClassName() works but when I click another item in my CellList my disabled styling is removed. Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve adding styles names by overriding  the render() method of your cell as follows -

```
@Override
public void render( com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, T value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb )
{   
    if( disable condition met )
    {
            // Apply disabled style
        sb.appendHtmlConstant( "<div class='css-style-disabled' >"+ value+" </div>" 
    } 
    else
    {
            super.render( context, value, sb );
    } 
}
```

So, add `css-style-disabled` class to your css file start styling it.

Comment: I like the idea of placing the logic in render() but in this case I'd need to extend my DTO to include the disabled state which I'd prefer to avoid as it's a commonly used class in my app.

Comment: I've since adopted using UiBinder to define the UI so this answer is no longer applicable to such an approach.

Answer (score 0):

texasbruce's answer is the solution but if you are using a ListDataProvider then you'll need to modify the timing of any call to addClassName() thus:

```
new Timer() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        << call cellList.getRowElement(0).addClassName("css-disabled") here >>;
    }
}.schedule(1);
```